# Getting new-tab function to work inside ng-repeat in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

I'm somewhat new to angular, and still trying to wrap my head around it.

Anyway, I'm trying to add new-tab buttons to a dynamically created list of links. I've added the name of the new tab function as a string in the links object, but this isn't working, and I feel like I'm approaching it in the wrong way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
//controller
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("nav", ["$scope", "$window", function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.newTabOne = function () {
        $window.open('http://example.com/#/1', '_blank');
        return $scope;
    };
    $scope.newTabTwo = function () {
        $window.open('http://example.com/#/2', '_blank');
        return $scope;
    };
    $scope.newTabThree = function () {
        $window.open('http://example.com/#/3', '_blank');
        return $scope;
    };

    $scope.links = [{name: 'Home', link: '#/Home', children: []},
                    {name: 'Drop Down 1', link: '', children: [
                            {name: 'One', link: '#/1', children: [], tab: 'newTabOne()'},
                            {name: 'Two', link: '#/2', children: [], tab: 'newTabTwo()'}
                     ]},
                     {name:'Drop Down 2', link:'', children:[
                            {name: 'Three', link: '#/3', children: [], tab: 'newTabThree()'}
                     ]}

    ];
}])

//view
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li ng-repeat="nav in links" >
        <a href="{{nav.link == '' ? 'javascript:;' : nav.link}}">
            <span class="text">{{topNav.name}}</span>
            <i ng-if="nav.children.length > 0" class="arrow fa fa-angle-right right"></i>
        </a>
        <ul ng-if="nav.children.length > 0" class="inner-drop list-unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="childNav in nav.children">
                <a href="{{childNav.link}}">
                    <span class="text">{{childNav.name}}</span>
                </a>
                <button ng-click="{{childNav.tab}}"></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this snippet. My recommendations

- Its NOT recommended to use $eval but if you want to evaluate the string as a function, this is the way to do it
- On a side note, use ng-href when you have the value coming from the controller.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("navCtrl", ["$scope", "$window",
    function($scope, $window) {

      $scope.newTabOne = function() {
        $window.open('http://example.com/#/1', '_blank');
        return $scope;
      };
      $scope.newTabTwo = function() {
        $window.open('http://example.com/#/2', '_blank');
        return $scope;
      };
      $scope.newTabThree = function() {
        $window.open('http://example.com/#/3', '_blank');
        return $scope;
      };

      $scope.links = [{
          name: 'Home',
          link: '#/Home',
          children: []
        }, {
          name: 'Drop Down 1',
          link: '',
          children: [{
            name: 'One',
            link: '#/1',
            children: [],
            tab: 'newTabOne()'
          }, {
            name: 'Two',
            link: '#/2',
            children: [],
            tab: 'newTabTwo()'
          }]
        }, {
          name: 'Drop Down 2',
          link: '',
          children: [{
            name: 'Three',
            link: '#/3',
            children: [],
            tab: 'newTabThree()'
          }]
        }

      ];
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li ng-repeat="nav in links">
        <a href="{{nav.link == '' ? 'javascript:;' : nav.link}}">
          <span class="text">{{topNav.name}}</span>
          <i ng-if="nav.children.length > 0" class="arrow fa fa-angle-right right"></i>
        </a>
        <ul ng-if="nav.children.length > 0" class="inner-drop list-unstyled">
          <li ng-repeat="childNav in nav.children">
            <a href="{{childNav.link}}">
              <span class="text">{{childNav.name}}</span>
            </a>
            <button ng-click="$eval(childNav.tab)">in New Window</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```